# Wrapping an element inside the innerHTML of another

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<div class="blue"><a href="#">link</a></div>
```

and I'm wanting to make

```
<div class="blue"><span class="orange"><a href="#">link</a></span></div>
```

How may I wrap a span inside the contents of `.blue`?

```
var blue = document.querySelector('.blue');

var orange = document.createElement('span');
orange.classList.add('orange');
```

Closest I've come is `blue.appendChild(orange);` but this places orange at the bottom of blue.

http://jsbin.com/zuxibakihi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var blue = document.querySelector('.blue');

var orange = document.createElement('span');
orange.classList.add('orange');

while (blue.childNodes.length > 0) {
    orange.appendChild(blue.childNodes[0]);
}

blue.appendChild(orange);
```

```css
div {background:blue}
a {background:red}
span {background:orange}
div,a,span {display:block;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="blue">   <a href="#">link</a><!--
    extra spaces  ^^^ or comments count as nodes, that is why "while" is a safe option 
even when in a simple html you think that you have a single node. --></div>
<br><br><br><br>
What I'm trying to do:
<div><span><a href="#">link</a></span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using insertBefore instead of appendChild, to insert at the first position inside blue.

```
var blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
blue.insertBefore(orange, blue.firstChild);
```

Similarly add it anywhere you require.